# OS programming using grub

Tags: operating-system, iso, grub

I found a website online to learn Operating system programming. I did the first tutorial and just followed with what they did. I came to the last step where I type "grub-mkrescue -o myos.iso isodir". However, I get a warning saying "your xorriso doesn't support '--grub2-boot-info' please use xorriso 1.2.9 or later". I'm not sure what to do. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

The tutorial I used is http://wiki.osdev.org/Bare_Bones. I tried writing it myself and also tried just copying the code and seeing if it works but I get the same problem.

I am also using Debian.

Comment: Read the Getting Started section on the page you linked, and the information in the GRUB link as well. Repetitiously re-entering the same command when the error message tells you it won't work and why, as well as what to to do fix it, isn't going to help you. Read the words in the error message. *Your 2014 Ford does not support voice commands. Please upgrade to a 2015 or higher model year.* seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may get xorriso from your operating system's package management as
either "xorriso" or "libisoburn" (where it is the command line frontend).
On Debian 8 and 9 it is

```
apt-get install xorriso
```

If no such package is offered or if it is too old (like in Debian 7),
then you may get the GNU xorriso tarball from

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/#download
```

Current stable release is:

```
https://www.gnu.org/software/xorriso/xorriso-1.4.6.tar.gz
```

Build by

```
tar xzf xorriso-1.4.6.tar.gz
cd xorriso-1.4.6
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
echo "Use with grub-mkrescue option --xorriso=$(pwd)/xorriso/xorriso"
```